# How can I import a pointcloud with vertex normals from .ply?

Tags: normals

I am attempting to render a series of around 1 million cubes by using dupliverts with a point cloud and a 'base' cube. I am able to import the points using .ply format, but when I inspect the vertex normals in edit mode, it seems that Blender is ignoring the vertex normals and simply computing them relative to the origin.

Is Blender capable of importing a point cloud with associated normals from .ply format? If not, can anyone recommend a format which would make this possible? My initial point cloud comes from a VTK file format, but I'm able to convert to others quite easily. I already tried X3D but I think this can only assign normals to higher dimensional geometry.